# getting the default contact app package name android

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to get the default contacts app of a device, I know a trick with creating an intent and get the apps that can open it, but whats the proper intent for contacts?

Comment: "I need to get the default contacts app of a device" -- why? Given that you have no idea what it is or what its capabilities are, what do you expect to do with it, even if you could figure out its identity?

Comment: launch an intent to open it, and get the app icon to show it.